# Create Ranges for a table by batchsize in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, range

How can I batch the records of a table and create ranges i.e., get Min and Max values for each batch?

Table has a volume of 15 million records and the unique key on the table (here, personID) is not sequential.

Input parameters:

```
     @TableName     NVARCHAR(250)  =’Person’
    ,@BatchColumn   NVARCHAR(250)  =’Personid’
    ,@BatchSize     INT      = 5
```

Sample table:

```
          personid  Name    EmailAddress
      1      1      Rob 
      2      3      Kate    
      3      5      Nate    
      4      8      Mary    
      5      9      Rama    
      6      11     Dan 
      7      15     Tom 
      8      17     Star    
      9      20     Berry   
      10     23     King    
      .      .      
      .      .      
      .      .      
     96      139        
     97      145        
     98      148        
     99      149        
     100     150        
     101     153    Sony    
     102     155    Duff
```

**Expected output:** with batchsize=5, each record has min and max values for every 5 records and the last bucket has min and max values of remaining records.

```
   Batch No.    Min Value   Max Value
     1             1             9
     2             11            23
     .             .              .
     .             .              .
     .             .              .
     20           139            150
     21           153            155
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL statement would use `row_number()` and some arithmetic:

```
select (1 + (seqnum - 1) / @batchSize) as batch, min(id), max(id)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by (seqnum - 1) / @batchSize
order by batch;
```